# C++) ihtmldocument2::put_charset Does not work with Meta tag

Tags: c++, mfc, ihtmldocument2

I want to change mht file's charset. So I used `ihtmldocument2::put_charset`

If file has no Meta tag charset, It does work. If file has Meta tag, put_charset does not work.

Here is my code.

```
LPDISPATCH lpDisp;
m_webBrowser->get_Document(&lpDisp);
lpDisp->QueryInterface(IID_IHTMLDocument2,(void**)&m_htmlDocument);
m_htmlDocument->put_charset(L"utf-8");
_variant_t rl=1L;   
m_webBrowser->Refresh2(&rl);
```

Comment: Using `CHtmlEditView` I was able to change charset between "ISO-8859-1" and "UTF-8".

Comment: Do you know the reason why "put_charset" does not working?